# Why does cat not use options the way I expect UNIX programs to use switches?

Tags: command-line, unix, cat

I have been a UNIX user for more years than I care to think about, and in that time I have been trained to expect that when contradictory switches are given to a program the last one wins.  Recently I have noticed that

```
cat -bn file
```

and

```
cat -nb file
```

both use the `-b` option (number non-blank lines) over the `-n` option (number all lines).  I get this behavior on both BSD and Linux, so I don't think it is an implementation quirk.  Is this something that is specified somewhere and am I just crazy for expecting the first example to number all lines?

Comment: You say that `-b` numbers blank lines. It actually causes **non-blank** lines to be numbered according to every man page I looked at (Ubuntu/GNU, FreeBSD, HP/UX).

Comment: @Dennis Williamson, yes, you are correct, that is a typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I took a look at the [FreeBSD source code for cat(1)](http://bxr.su/freebsd/bin/cat/cat.c#main), and the relevant source lines are:

```
case 'b':
    bflag = nflag = 1;  /* -b implies -n */
```

So this looks like a deliberate design decision; the interpretation of `-b` is that it modifies the behavior of `-n`, rather than `-b` and `-n` being two mutually exclusive alternatives.

Comment: That is an odd decision because they are documented to behave differently (number all lines vs number blank lines).  If `-n` were documented to "number lines" without the word "all", I would agree with the code.  Hmm, but looking at the BSD manpage it says "Number the output lines, starting at 1", so this is really just a problem with GNU cat's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Most system commands use C standard library getopt(3) or some variation, and parse the options from left to right. So, as you observed, last one wins.

Comment: That's the behavior he expects, but in the case he's asking about, the last one doesn't win.

Comment: You already covered that. I was explaining why the usual mechanism usually favors rightmost arguments.